# Crashlytics Android Library Project

Tags: android, crashlytics

I have created my own library project and want to get crash reports by Crashlytics. My goal is to filter crashes - I want to receive crash reports only from my library not from 3rd party app. Is it possible ?

Comment: did the answer below work for you ?
I am trying to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ACRA library it will give you all stack trace by setting it.you can send on your server the crash report or mail or write in local file

https://github.com/ACRA/acra